# Python use curl with subprocess, write outpute into file

Tags: python, curl

If I use the following command in the Git Bash, it works fine. The Output from the curl are write into the file output.txt

```
curl -k --silent "https://gitlab.myurl.com/api/v4/groups?page=1&per_page=1&simple=yes&private_token=mytoken&all?page=1&per_page=1" > output.txt
```

Python Code:

```
import subprocess, shlex
command = shlex.split("curl -k --silent https://gitlab.myurl.com/api/v4/groups?page=1&per_page=1&simple=yes&private_token=mytoken&all?page=1&per_page=1 > output.txt")
subprocess.Popen(command)
```

The Python code write nothing in my file "output.txt".
How can I write in the output.txt  or get the Output direct in Python?

Comment: use the module pycurl

Comment: i want make my script just with the standard library

Comment: hi, please check your first command, it has a duplicated `curl -k --silent`

Comment: thx, i have fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use redirection directly with subprocess, because it is a shell feature. Use `check_output`:

```
import subprocess
command = ["curl", "-k", "--silent", "https://gitlab.myurl.com/api/v4/groups?page=1&per_page=1&simple=yes&private_token=mytoken&all?page=1&per_page=1"]
output = subprocess.check_output(command)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the command in another way in order to write to *output.txt*:

```
curl -k --silent "https://gitlab.myurl.com/api/v4/groups?page=1&per_page=1&simple=yes&private_token=mytoken&all?page=1&per_page=1" --output output.txt
```

Also you should consider that *output.txt* might not be saved in the directory you expect so I would also advice you to name *output.txt* in another way, a unique one, then update the `locate` linux command database (see `updatedb` command) and then search the file with `locate`.

PS: all this make sense when you need the writing to *output.txt* (your question accepts this situation too, so I hope it helps)

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation. I know you are new here so even if you'd like to appreciate my answer with an up vote you wouldn't be able :)